# PHP - Listing contents of database entries

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to list all of the entries in a db table via php.

Here is a preview of the db:

[image]

Here is my php code:

```
<?PHP
include('config.php');
$db_found = mysql_select_db($dbase, $db_handle);
if ($db_found) 
{
    $xSQL = "SELECT * FROM Logins";
    $result = mysql_query($xSQL);
    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo $db_field['Username'] . ":" . $db_feild['Password'] . '<br />';    
    }
}
else 
    {
        print "Database NOT Found ";
        mysql_close($db_handle);
    }
?>
```

And here is the final result:

[image]

I would expect the result to display:

username2:password1

username1:password1

I am missing the error in my code if any. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you storing plain text passwords?

Comment: It is just an example. There aren't actually user's information, otherwise yes, I would use password hashing.

Comment: Running a database query in PHP *works*. The error is on your side and requires basic debugging first. Enable error reporting to the highest level for development so you get informed about unset variables and indexes which point you to mistakes early.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check your echo, it reads:
$db_feild

it should be $db_field

hope that solves it

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'll accept you answer, when it lets me in 12 mins, lol.

Answer (score 2):

If you cut/paste your code, you mis-spelled $db_field['Password']

Comment: How would that make sense? If I cut/paste then I misspelled? I beg to differ. If I cut/paste then I would not have misspelled. The misspelling happened due to the sole reason that I do not cut/paste.

Comment: Hi Josh,  I meant if your quoted code was a cut/paste from your IDE.  Nonetheless, glad you got it resolved.